# Create select input value with the ability to fill yourself in React

Tags: reactjs, select, input

I need to make input field with the ability to add non-selected name. I've created extra field for this: so when user select "other" from a list the new field appears.

But the problem is that when I fill new field it changes status because both these field have same value={this.state.company}

My working code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-form-sg5wr

I need to be able save value: if it's partner1 - save it, if it's other - then write other name and save it. But value should go like one value (value={this.state.company}). Maybe there is a way not adding new filed? Like if it's not in the list then write it.
Thanks in advance!

**UPD:** I've solved it just adding the third hidden input with

```
value={this.state.company === "other" ? this.state.companyOther : this.state.company}
```

and change setState.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty easy to handle using the state. You cannot do it in your own procedures when you are updating the same state again and again. You can declare a new state called `companyOther` and use the following condition in your `handleSubmit`,

```
this.state.company === "other" ? this.state.companyOther : this.state.company
```

Comment: Thanks. I got your point but not completely understand how can I change it using this.setState({request: '',company:''}) ...